# Multiple word string for database search using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli

In trying to set up a contact database I'm trying to use a multi word string to search a database of people to narrow down search results.
I have the following code. My problem is taking the result of my forms input string converted to an array and inserting it into the $sql SELECT coding so that it checks every word against every column. The reason for that is so when doing a search you can either type in 'Joe Bloggs New York' or 'New York Joe Bloggs' and get the same result.

```
<?php   

// **My String collection and conversion to an array** 

// Get Form String

$input = $_POST['input'];

// Split String into an Array

$input = preg_split("/[\\/\s,]+/", $input);

// Checking That We Now Have An Array

    print_r($input);

// Loop Through Array Values

for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {

// Checking Array Output

    echo '<br />';
    echo $input[$i];
    echo '<br />';
}

// **My database query**

// Connect To Database

require_once("connect.php"); 

// Query The Database

$sql="SELECT * FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$input[$i]%' AND lastName LIKE '%$input[$i]%' AND area LIKE '%$input[$i]%' ORDER BY name";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

  // Fetch one and one row

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo "<h2><u>$row[1]</u></h2><br />"; 
    echo "<img src='img/$row[5]' style='width:300px; height: auto;'/>"; 
    echo "<h3>Name - $row[1] $row[2]</h3>"; 
    echo "<h3>Phone - $row[3]</h3>"; 
    echo "<h3>Email - $row[4]</h3>"; 
    echo "<br /><br />";
    }

  // Free result set

mysqli_free_result($result);

} else {
    echo "No Results";
}

// Close Database Connection

mysqli_close($con);
?>

    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <form method="post" action="search.php">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                 <input type="text" name="input" size="30" maxlength="50"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="submit" name="SEARCH" value="Search"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
</form>
```

If I could please get help putting both pieces of code together so that it takes the string, converts it to an array and then only gives me a return from the database of Joe Bloggs's that live in New York I'd be very grateful.

Comment: why dont you break down the search so you search on name separately to location?

Comment: Have different fields for different information in search form. Keep things organized

Comment: Or use FULLTEXT search.

Comment: Trying not to have multiple search fields in a form, I can do that. I'm trying to achieve like on amazon where you don't have multiple fields to look for a men's red shirt, it's all in the one input field. I'll look more into the FULLTEXT search. Thanks for all your help and suggestions

Comment: Amazon might be looking by title and/or description body where you can label "men's red shirt". Imagine how many fields you'll need to cover every parameter for absolutely everything that is possible to sell. One search query could take hours to yield results.

Comment: You are evaluating the expression outside the for loop. Thus, '%$input[$i]%' evaluates to '%%' matching all db entries.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing your ANDs to ORs in the query, otherwise you are querying for john john who lives in john...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try and I still get at the top the 'print' output of the array '(Array ( [0] => Joe [1] => bloggs [2] => new [3] => york ) ' and then the individual outputs from the loop. After that though it still gives me the entire database listed out again

Comment: So another issue I noticed that you are only looping over $i for the echo statements. Shouldn't your close brace be after you query?